# looping through files for postgresql give error in windows

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, batch-processing

i'm trying to read files and load them all csv files, and once done move the files to some other location :

```
cd E:\data\
for /f %%a in (’dir /b filename*.CSV) do (
   psql -U postgre -W password -c "COPY INTO LA from %%a" zipcodes
   mv %%a E:\data\bc\
)
```

but it gives me following error:

```
E:\data>for /F %a in (ΓÇÖdir /b filename*.CSV) do (
psql -U postgre -W password-c "COPY INTO LA from %a" zipcodes
 mv %a E:\data\bc\
)
The system cannot find the file ΓÇÖdir.
```

thanks for help

Comment: Your `’` is a "pretty" quote, use a regular one (`'`)

Comment: I still get file not found error ( mv %a E:\loadpg\data\bc\
)
The system cannot find the file 'dir /b filename*.CSV.)

Comment: Do you mean `move` instead of `mv` (which does not exist on windows by default)

Comment: yes moving them I confused with linux... but still the error is in part of cannot be found  (The system cannot find the file 'dir /b filename*.CSV.)

Comment: You need to close the string; `for /f %%a in ('dir /b filename*.CSV') do (`

Comment: okay thanks I did that but still it says file not found :

E:\data>for /F %a in ('dir /b filename*.CSV') do (
psql -U postgre -W password -c "COPY INTO LA from %a" zipcode

 move %a E:\data\bc\
)
File Not Found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "psql=c:\wherever\psqlIs\psql.exe"

    pushd "e:\data" && (
        for %%a in ("filename*.CSV") do (
           "%psql%" -U postgre -W password -c "COPY INTO LA from %%~a" zipcodes
           move "%%~a" "E:\data\bc\"
        )
        popd
    )
```

`for /f` is intended for file/string processing. To iterate over a set of files use a simple `for`

Anyway, the problem in your code are the opening single quote (as Alex K has pointed), the missing closing quote and the non existing `mv` command in windows that should be `move`

**edited** it seems there are problems with file loading. psql `copy` command indicates it is better to use full path names (with backslashes doubled), so

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "psql=c:\wherever\psqlIs\psql.exe"

    pushd "e:\data" && (
        for %%a in ("filename*.CSV") do (
            set "file=%%~fa"
           "%psql%" -U postgre -W password -c "COPY INTO LA from  E'!file:\=\\!'" zipcodes
           move "%%~a" "E:\data\bc\"
        )
        popd
    )
```

Comment: thanks but your code only change the directory and then print out the rest of the code in screen it's not looping through files and not initiating the psql to load them

Comment: @hi4ppl, obviously, if there are no `filenames*.csv` they will not be found and if `psql` is not accesible in the current folder or in the path it will not be called

Comment: okay thanks got it... do you know how to add fully qualified name of pg like path of psql as it looks like the path is not global and is not accessible for some reason

Comment: @hi4ppl, you can modify your system/user `path` variable from control panel, or, for a simply command call, use the method pointed in the answer (updated again to ensure only the adequated files are processed).

Comment: never mind I had to give full path of the file in loop it works now thanks

Comment: @hi4ppl, sorry, psql is not my area, but i've included a modified version with the recomendations from documentation. Sorry, i can help with the batch but not with the database tools.

Comment: Thanks I put the path in envi variable and it works fine thanks for help

Comment: one last help. in bellow location I have files in sub folders :

for %%a in ("E:\data\*.CSV") do (

how can I search inside sub-folders and process them also? as this one only get data of main folder 
i.e 
data/data1
data/data2

Comment: @hi4ppl `for /r "e:\data" %%a in ("filename*.csv") ...` This will do a recursive search of the files. Be sure to reference the file as `"%%~fa"` to get the full path of the file.